# What is the use of ".yml" files in perl/perl modules

Tags: perl, yaml

What is the use of ".yml" files in perl/perl module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Wooble's point, YAML is particularly useful because it maps cleanly to Perl hashrefs. For example:

```
company:
    acme:
        label: Acme
    xyzcorp:
        label: XYZ Corp
```

can be cleanly mapped by Perl's YAML modules into this:

```
{
    acme => { label => Acme },
    xyzcorp => { label => XYZ Corp }
}
```

It's a lot like JSON in that respect.

Answer (score 7):

YAML (YAML Ain't Markup Language) is generally used for configuration files, as it's a convenient machine-readable format that's also designed to be easy for humans to read and write.

*Expanding based on toolic's comment:*

**META.yml** is generated by the build process with tools like `Module::Build` and `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, and contains metadata about the module to be used by CPAN or other package-management tools.